# How to set password on first call for command from paramiko?

Tags: python, unix, paramiko, change-password

I have one user `test`.

I set password change when that user login with `chage` command.

```
chage -E 2012-01-25 -M 30 -d 0 -W 10 -I 5 test
```

So when i try to run command `ls`

```
[root@localhost ~]# ssh test@localhost "ls"
WARNING: Your password has expired.
Password change required but no TTY available.
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

Then i try to connect with `ssh`

```
[root@localhost ~]# ssh test@localhost
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Last login: Tue Dec 27 09:55:55 2011 from localhost
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user test.
Changing password for test.
(current) UNIX password:
```

And than i can set the password for the user.

If I try to connect the same with `paramiko`.

```
In [1]: import paramiko

In [2]: ssh_conn = paramiko.SSHClient()

In [3]: ssh_conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

In [4]: ssh_conn.load_system_host_keys()

In [5]: ssh_conn.connect('n2001', username='root_acc23', password='test')

In [6]: a = ssh_conn.exec_command('ls')

In [7]: print a[2].read()
WARNING: Your password has expired.
Password change required but no TTY available.
```

Then I do some google and find some solution to set new password with `invoke_shell` show I wrote one function

```
def chage_password_change(ssh_conn, password, curr_pass):
   '''
   If got error on login then set with interactive mode.
   '''
   interact = ssh_conn.invoke_shell()
   buff = ''
   while not buff.endswith('UNIX password: '):
       resp = interact.recv(9999)
       buff += resp
   interact.send(curr_pass + '\n')

   buff = ''
   while not buff.endswith('New password: '):
       resp = interact.recv(9999)
       buff += resp

   interact.send(password + '\n')

   buff = ''
   while not buff.endswith('Retype new password: '):
       resp = interact.recv(9999)
       buff += resp

   interact.send(password + '\n')


   interact.shutdown(2)
   if interact.exit_status_ready():
       print "EXIT :", interact.recv_exit_status()

   print "Last Password"
   print "LST :", interact.recv(-1)
```

This is working in some cases like when we give proper password with digits, alpa and special character combination.

But when we give some short password or error occur in password change like this

```
[root@localhost ~]# ssh test@localhost
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Last login: Tue Dec 27 10:41:15 2011 from localhost
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user test.
Changing password for test.
(current) UNIX password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
BAD PASSWORD: it is too short
```

In this command we got error **BAD PASSWORD: it is too short** So this I cant determine in my function. I get this error when I do `interact.recv(-1)` but this is the stdout I think. So is there any way to determine that this is the error.

I check the paramiko doc and find that `Channel` class has some method `recv_stderr_ready` and `recv_stderr` but this error not come in that data.

Thx for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy answer is to have your function check the length of the password BEFORE you invoke your shell, if you know what the cutoff is.  Better performance, too.  But if you don't know the cutoff, that won't work.

I'm not clear from your description, but if the BAD PASSWORD message comes back from interact.recv(-1), then you know it happened, and can proceed accordingly.  It seems that it should be coming back from either std err or stdout, so check both.  If you know what text comes back if the new password was accepted, then you can check for that as well; whichever one you get first tells you what happened, and your function can go on from there.

Comment: Thx @ScottHunter for your reply. I know the error might be 2-3 possible words. I want to raise error if i get output in stderr without checking stdout. If i have to check stdout and stderr for error then I have to check each time in stdout.

Comment: Unfortunately, if stdout is where the error message is being written, that's where you have to read it from.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

this might work also, if you are looking for an expired password change method.
(python 3)

```
import time
from contextlib import closing
import paramiko

def wait_until_channel_endswith(channel, endswith, wait_in_seconds=15):
    """Continues execution if the specified string appears at the end of the channel

    Raises: TimeoutError if string cannot be found on the channel
    """

    timeout = time.time() + wait_in_seconds
    read_buffer = b''
    while not read_buffer.endswith(endswith):
        if channel.recv_ready():
           read_buffer += channel.recv(4096)
        elif time.time() > timeout:
            raise TimeoutError(f"Timeout while waiting for '{endswith}' on the channel")
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

def change_expired_password_over_ssh(host, username, current_password, new_password):
    """Changes expired password over SSH with paramiko"""
    with closing(paramiko.SSHClient()) as ssh_connection:
        ssh_connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh_connection.connect(hostname=host, username=username, password=current_password)
        ssh_channel = ssh_connection.invoke_shell()

        wait_until_channel_endswith(ssh_channel, b'UNIX password: ')
        ssh_channel.send(f'{current_password}\n')

        wait_until_channel_endswith(ssh_channel, b'New password: ')
        ssh_channel.send(f'{new_password}\n')

        wait_until_channel_endswith(ssh_channel, b'Retype new password: ')
        ssh_channel.send(f'{new_password}\n')

        wait_until_channel_endswith(ssh_channel, b'all authentication tokens updated successfully.\r\n')
```

Usage:

```
change_expired_password_over_ssh('192.168.1.1', 'username', 'expired-password', 'new-password')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following lines might be a problematic and might cause some bugs:

```
while not buff.endswith('Retype new password: '):
      resp = interact.recv(9999)
      buff += resp // this will append the output from the shell
```

code fix:

it will better to use it this way

```
while not buff.endswith('Retype new password: '):
     resp = interact.recv(9999)
     buff = resp
```

now each iteration of the loop, will parse the current \ updated, output text from the shell.

Regards,
Eldad